# Getting ListBoxItem from item template control event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

In the WPF XAML code below, if I am in the SelectTaskItemClick event for the templated Button, how do I get the ListBoxItem ItemSource object that is currently selected?

```
    <!-- ListBox ITEMS -->
    <TaskDash:ListBoxWithAddRemove x:Name="listBoxItems" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="3"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <!--ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Description">-->
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
        </Style>
        <TaskDash:ListBoxWithAddRemove.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Click="SelectTaskItemClick">SELECT</Button>
                    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="EditableDescription" Text="{Binding Description}" Height="25" Width="100" />
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Click="EditTaskItemClick">EDIT</Button>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TaskDash:ListBoxWithAddRemove.ItemTemplate>
    </TaskDash:ListBoxWithAddRemove>
```

If I try to get the Parent or TemplateParent, it gives me the ContentPresenter or Style or something similar.

```
    private void SelectTaskItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button taskItemButton = (Button) e.OriginalSource;
        ContentPresenter taskItem = (ContentPresenter) taskItemButton.TemplatedParent;
        taskItem = (ContentPresenter)taskItemButton.TemplatedParent;
        Style taskItem2 = taskItem.TemplatedParent;
        taskItem2 = taskItem.TemplatedParent;
        DependencyObject taskItem3 = taskItem2.Parent;
        //DependencyObject taskItem3 = taskItem2.TemplatedParent;
        //TaskItem taskItemObj = taskItem2;
    }
```

In the code above, I'm guessing it is grabbing that from App.XAML where that custom ListBoxWithAddRemove control is defined. How do I traverse the actual form's XAML instead [the first code shown above]?

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TaskDash:ListBoxWithAddRemove}" TargetType="{x:Type     TaskDash:ListBoxWithAddRemove}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TaskDash:ListBoxWithAddRemove}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                                    Click="DeleteControlClick">Delete</Button>
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                                    Click="AddControlClick">Add</Button>
                            <Border 
                                Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  Name="Border" 
                                  Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                                  BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
                                  BorderThickness="1"
                                  CornerRadius="2">
                                <ScrollViewer 
                                    Margin="0"
                                    Focusable="false">
                                    <StackPanel Margin="0" IsItemsHost="True" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `VisualTreeHelper` to walk up the tree and stop if you have an object of the right type, e.g.

```
private void SelectTaskItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var b = sender as Button;
    DependencyObject item = b;
    while (item is ListBoxItem == false)
    {
        item = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
    }
    var lbi = (ListBoxItem)item;
    //...
}
```

(*If you just want to select the item that can (and should) just be done via the established binding, e.g.*)

```
private void SelectTaskItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // The DataContext should be an item of your class that should
    // have a Selected property as you bind to it in a style.
    var data = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyClass;
    data.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is mostly what I needed. It looks like what I also needed to do was remove the Style element. I kept getting a ListBoxItem with a DataContext of STYLE instead of TASKITEM:

<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
            </Style>

Comment: @Shawn: The style is fine by iteself, but you should not add it to the ListBox like you did but set it as its `ItemContainerStyle`: `<TaskDash:ListBoxWithAddRemove.ItemContainerStyle><!-- Style here --></TaskDash:ListBoxWithAddRemove.ItemContainerStyle>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
</Style>
```

works the way that it appears you intended, you should be able to loop through the items  in your DataContext used as the ItemsSource for your listbox and check the Selected property of each to find the one currently selected.  The more typical way of determining the selected item from a ListBox is by using listBox.SelectedItem where listBox is a variable that refers to the ListBox in question.  Alternatively you might be able to access it off the `sender` parameter to the `SelectTaskItemClick` method.  Another method you might try is helper methods to traverse the visual tree such as described at [The Coding Bloke](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx), and [The Code Project - LINQ to Visual Tree](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63157/LINQ-to-Visual-Tree?display=Print).

Comment: I think the point of the button is to select the item that was clicked, so it is not selected beforehand.